# Place 3d object on real object in Augmented Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am new to Augmented Reality, and I am creating a application where I will scan products and then I need to place 3d object on it to explain features.
Let say I am scanning a remote control, after scanning I have to show what on/off button do by pointing at it,
What volume button do by pointing at it, what channel button do by pointing at it etc

I searched a lot on internet couldn't find anything

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Microsoft had pumped a billion dollars into this question with the hololens (and it still isn't complete). How much do you think you can do in a few weeks?

Comment: But I have seen people are making applications like this for ex https://youtu.be/aQyH7CQPVcA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to generate a cad 3d model object which simulate your real model then from MTG application provided by vuforia create your model specific dataset after generating try to import it in unity and add to model target in your app. Now you can map your 3d model to real world object.

Comment: and how we can do it without vuforia and using  arcore.